# If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)=L \neq 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

In the following proof, we will argue that:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)=L \neq 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$.

It will be straightforward to see that this argument can be amended to also prove:

> If $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $g(a) \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{g}$ is also continuous at $a$.

---

By assumption $L \neq 0$, which means that $L \lt 0$ or $L \gt 0$. Suppose the former.

By assumption, we know that there is a $\delta_{\eta} \gt 0$ such that for any $x \in (a-\delta_{\eta}, a+\delta_{\eta}) \setminus \{a\}:$ $L-\eta \lt g(x) \lt L+\eta \lt 0$, where $0 \lt \eta \lt |L|$.

Under these conditions, we have that $\frac{1}{L+\eta} \lt \frac{1}{g(x)} \lt \frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt 0$.

Our goal is to determine if for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is an $0 \lt \eta \lt |L|$ such that, for any $x \in (a-\delta_{\eta}, a+\delta_{\eta}) \setminus \{a\}:$

$$\frac{1}{L}-\varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{L+\eta} \lt \frac{1}{g(x)} \lt \frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt \frac{1}{L}+\varepsilon$$

Working backwards, suppose $\frac{1}{L}-\varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{L+\eta}$. Assuming $\eta \lt |L|$, we know that $\frac{1}{L+\eta} \lt 0$. This inequality can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1-\varepsilon L}{L} \lt \frac{1}{L+\eta} \iff L+\eta \lt \frac{L}{1-\varepsilon L} \iff \eta \lt \frac{L-L(1-\varepsilon L)}{1-\varepsilon L}=\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1-\varepsilon L}$$

Because $\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1-\varepsilon L} \gt 0$, this is a valid candidate for $\eta$. *Note that all of the above inequality manipulations are reversible...biconditionally related*. As such, in order for $\frac{1}{L}-\varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{L+\eta}$, we must also have $\eta \lt \min\left(|L|,\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1-\varepsilon L}\right) \quad (*_1)$.

Working backwards again, suppose $\frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt \frac{1}{L}+\varepsilon$. Assuming that $0 \lt \eta \lt |L|$, we know that $\frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt 0$. Therefore, if $\varepsilon \geq \left|\frac{1}{L}\right|$, then $\frac{1}{L}+\varepsilon \geq 0$. This means that any $\eta \in (0,|L|)$ will work. So suppose $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt \left|\frac{1}{L}\right|$, which means that we are working backwards from the statement: $\frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt \frac{1}{L}+\varepsilon \lt 0$. This inequality can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt \frac{1+\varepsilon L}{L} \iff \frac{L}{1+\varepsilon L} \lt L-\eta \iff \eta \lt \frac{L(1+\varepsilon L)-L}{1+\varepsilon L}=\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1+\varepsilon L}$$

Because $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{-L}$, we have that $\varepsilon L \gt -1$, which of course means that $1+\varepsilon L \gt 0$. Therefore, $\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1+\varepsilon L} \gt 0$, which means that this is a valid candidate for $\eta$. In order for $\frac{1}{L-\eta} \lt \frac{1}{L}+\varepsilon$, we require that $\eta \lt \min \left(|L|,\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1+\varepsilon L} \right) \quad (*_2)$.

In conclusion, in order to satisfy both $(*_1)$ and $(*_2)$, we require that:

> if $\varepsilon \geq \left|\frac{1}{L}\right|$ \begin{align} 0 \lt \eta \lt \min\left(|L|, \frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1-\varepsilon L}\right) \end{align} and if $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt \left|\frac{1}{L}\right|$ \begin{align}0 \lt \eta \lt \min\left(|L|, \frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1-\varepsilon L},\frac{\varepsilon L^2}{1+\varepsilon L}\right)  \end{align}

A similar argument can be used to show that the claim holds if $L \gt 0$.

This proves that: If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)=L \neq 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$.

---

This proof looked a little different than my book's presentation of the same theorem: I just wanted to make sure that I did not overlook any possible mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is more insightful to show a more general result, namely that

> If a function $f$ is continuous at $a$ then$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a) = f\Big(\lim_{x\to a} x\Big)$$i.e. one may swap taking a limit and evaluating a function provided the function is continuous.

In your specific case, the result reads

$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = L \quad\implies\quad f(L) = f\Big(\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\Big) = \lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))$$
for the special case $f(x) = 1/x$ because that $f$ is continuous for $x\neq 0$.

The advantage is that one won't get lost in the arithmetic details of a  specific function $f$, but instead to use generic properties one gets from the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I like this method, but I reckon in order to know that $f(x)=1/x$ is a continuous function for $x \neq 0$, you necessarily need to 'get lost in the arithmetic details' (assuming, of course, you are not making use of the theorem I posted). i.e. you would need to first derive that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Yes, one will get lost in the arithmetic *once*.  It's one of the first theorems after intruducing the concept of continuity, that basic arithmetic `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and composition is continuous. You will need / use this over and over again, and IMO it's a plus to know one's toolbox.  If you'll have to deal with a polynomial like $x^2-x+1$ yu don't want to show continuity for this one specific polynomial, and then the next week for $x^3+x-2$ etc.  It's clear that you don't have control over how the topic is being introduced, though.